# Animated gif doesn't display on command

Tags: javascript, raphael, repeat, animated-gif

I have an animated gif and I am running it in Raphael Javascript.

The following code displays the gif:

```
raphael_paper.image("animation.gif", 500,500, 100,100);
```

The problem I am having is that I can only have the gif run once. After first run this code does not make the gif display at all.
How do get the gif to display repeatedly on command?

Comment: so you will see the animation once and then the image disappears?

Comment: well the gif once run, is just a wholly transparent sheet. So i can't even see if it's there. But it's supposed to make another anyways for the code is being run again.

Comment: So you call the image function once, runs once, turns transparent. You call the image function again and the image does not appear at all. Do I understand?

Comment: yes, thats the way it is.

Comment: The image function returns a Raphaël element object with type "image". So you should store that element like so `var image = paper.image(uri, x, y, w, h);`. Then try to do what you want with that element or try to pass that element as an argument to the image function.

Comment: yes as bizarre as it may seem, doing var image=.. has the exact same effect.. the animated gif gets displayed as well. can you show me an example of how its done youre talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/187/)**

```
var r = new Raphael(10,10, 500, 500),
    i = r.image
    (
        "http://brucebeatz.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/gif01djlogoanimado.gif", 
        30, 30, 300, 300
    );
```

**You can see that in this demo the animation does not stop.** Am I misunderstanding you question?

Comment: yeah but the animation doesn't stop anyways. If it were an animation that would play and finish, and then when you click a button or something like that.. play again, that's what im looking for.

Comment: or another instance of the animated gif would play.

Comment: No, the gif animation format nerver stops playing. If you find any examples, you can see that it is constantly playing. If you need the animation to play only once, then you need different type

Comment: the loop option in the convert command can make it play only once.